# Get node position and length of edge

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Can someone tell me how to get the nodes' position and the length of the edge without calculating it myself?

```
import networkx as nx    
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge('a','b')
```

Comment: There is no specified position for the nodes until you've defined them with something like `pos = nx.spring_layout(G)`.  Until then it's just a graph - just nodes connected by edges.  There's no geometry.

Comment: So the random positions nx.draw(G) gives are not accessible?

Comment: `nx.draw(G)` uses `spring_layout` by default, but it's random each time, and it doesn't return those values.  If you want to have the positions that things are drawn at, define the positions before drawing and pass them to `nx.draw`.  So you do `pos = ns.spring_layout(G)` and then `nx.draw(G,pos=pos)`.  The positions are stored in `pos`.

Comment: Thank you. (Now that you say it I realize that it is `nx.draw(G)` and not `G.draw()`, so hoping those values could be found somewhere inside G probably didn't make to much sense anyway.)

Answer (score 4):

Nodes don't have any position unless you assign one to them. Fortunately Networkx has some layout algorithm [already implemented:](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/drawing.html#module-networkx.drawing.layout)

```
# Position nodes on a circle.
pos = circular_layout(G[, dim, scale])

# Position nodes uniformly at random in the unit square.
pos = random_layout(G[, dim])

# Position nodes in concentric circles.
pos = shell_layout(G[, nlist, dim, scale])  

# Position nodes using Fruchterman-Reingold force-directed algorithm.
pos = spring_layout(G[, dim, k, pos, fixed, ...])   

# Position nodes using the eigenvectors of the graph Laplacian.
pos = spectral_layout(G[, dim, weight, scale])
```

The return value `pos` is a dictionary of positions indexed by the node.

There are no function which would give the length of edges builtin but once you have the coordinates of each node you can compute the length of an edge using the simple formula:

```
import math
dist_node12 = math.sqrt((pos[node1][0] - pos[node2][0])**2 + (pos[node1][1] - pos[node2][1])**2)
```